# Elasticsearch remote access between two separate ubuntu servers

Tags: 16.04, server, remote-access, elasticsearch

We are running a website on ubuntu 16.04 where we are going to use a search function that uses Elasticsearch. We plan to have multiple projects with each project having two indexes. For that reason we setup another ubuntu server with a decent ram only for housing Elasticsearch.

Our question is; Whats the best way to integrate these two servers to be able to use Elasticsearch on the website? Is there a plugin to use to further secure the integration or our best shot is to use ES's configs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution. 
In elasticsearch.yml we did the following:

```
network.host: internal ip address of ES server (Server B)
http.port: 9200
transport.host: internal ip address of ES server (Server B)
transport.tcp.port: 9300
```

We gave the internal IP address of the server which houses Elasticsearch (Server B). And then in the firewall we gave access permission for the internal IP of the application server (Server A). (These two servers are in the same network in the data center).

By that we are able to curl from Server A using the internal IP of Server B to get results from Elasticsearch.

Now we are getting the following result from Php.

```
array(2) { ["result"]=> bool(true) ["data"]=> array(3) { ["acknowledged"]=> bool(true) ["shards_acknowledged"]=> bool(true) ["index"]=> string(23) "project_name" } }
```

For anyone interested in some more details I'll be glad to help.